# The fusion categories with a strict skeleton

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

We refer to the book [Tensor Categories](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3242743) (by Etingof-Gelaki-Nikshych-Ostrik) for all the notions mentioned in this post.

A fusion category is *skeletal* if two isomorphic objects are always equal. Every fusion category is equivalent to a skeletal one (i.e. a *skeleton*, by choosing one object in each isomorphism class). A fusion category is *strict* if its associativity (and unit) isomorphisms are identities.

**Question**: What are the fusion categories with a strict skeleton?

A fusion category is *pointed* (i.e. every simple object is invertible) if and only if it is equivalent to $\mathrm{Vec}_G^{\omega}$, where $G$ is a finite group and $\omega$ a $3$-cocycle. It admits a strict skeleton if and only if $\omega$ is trivial.  What are the non-pointed examples (if any)?

The *multiplicity* of a fusion category is the maximum of its fusion coefficients $(N_{ij}^k)$. A pointed fusion category is of multiplicity one (the converse is false, see $\mathrm{Rep}(S_3)$).

**Theorem**: A fusion category with a strict skeleton is of multiplicity one.

*Proof*: consider Remark 4.10.8 (in above book, p79-80), which provides a necessary condition for a fusion ring to admit a strict skeletal categorification. We will show that this condition implies that the multiplicity is one (the converse, useless here, is easy to see). Let us take the notation of Remark 4.10.8. If $j=1$ (corresponding to the trivial simple object), then:
$$ id_{N_{i1}^i} \otimes g \otimes id_{N_{il}^s} = id_{N_{il}^s} \otimes g \otimes id_{N_{1l}^l},$$
where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Now $N_{i1}^i = N_{1l}^l = 1$, so:
$$ g \otimes id_{N_{il}^s} = id_{N_{il}^s} \otimes g, $$
but $g$ is a generic matrix, so $N_{il}^s \le 1$. $\square$

Comment: One note: Giving a skeleton requires not just “choosing one object in each isomorphism class” but also choosing, for each object, some isomorphism to its representative.  This is worth being explicit about, since the induced associator and unitor on the skeleton may depend on these choices of isomorphisms.